# How to find the selected ChekboxButton in a Column in Bokeh? Calendar using Checkboxes

Tags: bokeh

I am trying to make a calendar with CheckButton groups in a column. The problem is that I can't figure out which button is selected.

```
group1 = CheckboxButtonGroup(
        labels=["05", "06","07", "08","09"], height=10)
group2 = CheckboxButtonGroup(
        labels=["12", "13","14", "15","16"] , height=10)
group3 = CheckboxButtonGroup(
        labels=["19", "20","21", "23","24"] , height=10)

calendar = column(group1, group2, group3)
```

I want a function as follows:

```
def returnDaySelected(calendar):
    return SelectedDay
```

I understand that I have three groups, and I have to make a few `ifs` to get the group I want. But still. I can't find the groups inside the column.

I tried printing `dir(calendar)` and `dir(calendar.children[0])` to see what is inside the column. But I could not find an attribute that would give me back the groups, let alone the selected button.

Any ideas in how to return the selected button? (Or all of the selected buttons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `calendar.children[0].children[0].active` returns a list of the buttons pressed, e.g., if the 2nd and 3rd buttons are pressed it will return `[1,2]` (counting from 0).

The `column.children[0]` returns just the WidgetBox. Another call is required to access its children.

```
def returnDaysSelected(calendar):
    selectedDays = []
        for iGroup in calendar.children[0].children:
        active = iGroup.active
        for iDay in active:
            selectedDays.append(iGroup.labels[iDay])
    return selectedDays
```